# How to set custom icons for folders with specified name?

Tags: windows, directory, icons, explorer, windows-explorer

Is there any way to assign a custom icon for folders with specified names like *.vscode .git images* etc?

In VS Code the *.vscode* folder, or *.git* folder and others like them all have a specific icon. You don't have to set the icons manually for each of the folders.

I am wondering if you can do the same in Windows Explorer.

I think there should be some registry key tweak in order to do so

[image: git folder icon]

This is a concept of what I am locking for. I just want to have an automatic system that can assign icons to folders and you don't have to change the icons manually for each folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using VSCode you can you any of the themes in the extensions section. [Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) is among the popular ones, and it's highly customizable. Although, this will only change the icons in the editor, but I hope it helps.

Comment: No I don't want to use the icons inly in VScode. I want it in my Windows Explorer. Is there ant plugins or add-on that can do that... There are some shell extensions that can enable the APK file icon. I am looking for something like that.

Comment: Maybe something like [FolderIco](https://www.folderico.com/)

Comment: I know that one, but I want do it automatically not manually... I am looking for some cmd commands or registry entry